# Dell XPS 15 (2015) driving U3011 monitor at native res

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-display, dell-xps

I'm trying to get my laptop to drive my monitor at its native resolution:

- **laptop** is the new Skylake [Dell XPS 15 9950](http://www.dell.com/uk/p/xps-15-9550-laptop/pd) which only has an HDMI output for video
- **monitor** is a [Dell U3011](http://www.dell.com/ed/business/p/dell-u3011/pd) with native resolution of 2560x1600

So far I haven't found a way of driving it at above 1920x1200.

I've attempted to create some custom resolutions that run at lower refresh frequencies to see if it's a bandwidth issue, but none of them have displayed properly, making a noisy pattern, or losing much of the screen off the right and bottom sides.

Is there a way to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I finally sorted this out.

Using the Intel HD Graphics Control Panel:

[image]

Make sure:

- You "Select Display" on the left to the U3011
- Add a width of 2560, height of 1600, refresh rate of 40
- Set the timing standard to CVT (I've no idea why, but this worked)

Then go into 'General Settings':

[image]

Choose the U3011 at the top, select the resolution and refresh rate, then apply. On the advanced tab, I also had 1) default quantization range 2) IT content disabled.